# How do I trigger code in a react native app (running in android) from the server, even if the app is in the background/not turned on?

Tags: android, react-native, service, push-notification

I need to run some code to control the volume of my phone using a React Native app remotely, from a server. How would I ensure that even if the app is in the background, or even if it's not turned on, I can receive a message from the server in my app, and accordingly change device volume? I have used Headless JS before to run services in the background using a persistent notification, but these were controlled by the app itself. In this scenario, however, I want a remote server to boot up the app and start a foreground service. How do I go about doing this? Should I be using push notifications?